# Should I take all my notes code from my actual job after leaving or should I help them after leaving?

Tags: resignation, europe, code

Right now I am working as an intern in a unit of a non-profit foundation. I am faced with an ethical dilemma, which is that I have been given the opportunity to start working as a biostatistician, without previous formal experience. What happens is that the work has degenerated a lot and the employees are treated badly, there are not many possibilities of rehiring and the effort that is made to develop and solve technical programming problems so that the researchers of this foundation can publish correct papers is underestimated. and have the data resolved.

Currently, I have already received offers from CROs and pharmaceutical companies that pay me more salaries and give me better conditions than my current employer, so I have decided to leave. But I was doing a lot of work with R and Python, which consisted of preparing a statistical report for my superiors.

I understand that the reports and all their content, the databases and all the information they contain belong to the company. Will it be seen as unprofessional or bad practise to take my code with me? I am almost certain that they won't ask for it  because They don't have anyone capable of working with this data, but If they ask, should I help them after I quit my job to continue fulfilling my tasks with no one in that position?

Edit:
To be completely honest with me and with you, one of the main reasons for leaving was because my direct superior said that my job (coding, consulting and all that) could literally be done by a "trained monkey". He is of the mentality that AI is going to replace us and that if he dedicated a couple of hours to it, he could know how to program in R and Python and everything, without ever having done anything before. I tried to explain the importance of what I've achieved since I've been here, but he didn't give it any value. That's why I don't feel entirely satisfied leaving a code that I know my boss won't know how to use (and doesn't give value to)

Comment: What does your contract say? It's almost boilerplate to include that you transfer all rights to results of your work, including code, reports etc. In which case the moment you leave a job, you ought to actually delete all that stuff, not to mention NOT "take it".

Comment: It doesn't talk about nothing like that, because, What the contract literally says is that I must "advise" researchers and set up databases, how I do it is my problem.

Comment: Then you may be in the clear. Or maybe not, we really cannot answer contract questions here so it will get closed here. For what it's worth though, why not simply ask them if you can?

Comment: I know that legally I can do it without problems, but I don't know if Im burning bridges here, or if that does matter at the end.

Comment: Oh, ok, i read from last sentence that it's not certain: "But I was wondering if when I leave, they can force me to also leave the code that I created to answer their questions.".

Maybe rework the question to make it about the how to best aprt this relationship, but also get to keep the code?

Comment: I changed the title and some of the body of the question, thank you @TymoteuszPaul

Comment: You should really talk to a lawyer, because I'd be surprised if you actually have any ownership over code you wrote while in the employ of a company or non-profit.

Comment: Where are you located?  In most of the West, definitely North America, they own any work product you created (unless there's very specific contract language).  So you can't just take it and leave them with nothing.

Comment: I'm located in Spain

Comment: @JorgeA I don't get why this question is framed so binary. Code is just bits and bytes on some device. Bits and bytes can be replicated without any loss to the original. So it's entirely possible (and easy) to take a copy with you while still leaving everything you worked on behind. The legality of taking a copy home is another question, but the practical side of things is quite clear.

Comment: @GenericUserName Your comment made me add the last edit, maybe I'll give your idea more credit and think about it more deeply

Comment: The "code" that is proper to take with you is the knowledge of how to write such code. In my experience, it is quite rare for any code written for one company to be useful anywhere else. (Finished products are useful elsewhere, but code, no.) But the concepts and how to write code are readily transferable.

Comment: @JorgeA: seeing your last edit, i do understand how you feel, your bosses remark was very unprofessional and simply rude. However, I'd advise against any actions of "revenge" or out of spite. Leave your code, it doesn't matter if they can use it or not. Take a copy with you if you really want (and are sure you're allowed to or at least don't get caught). Find a better job & boss, the job market is wide open for skilled IT- and data scientists. Maybe in a couple months you'll get an email from your old boss, begging you to help out since AI failed him. Then you'll be the one laughing :)

Comment: Let me ask you a question. If instead of writing code, you were working for a bread baking company making the baking pans into which other employees put the dough in to make and bake bread. Would you be able to take away the baking pans you made? Of course not. You will be able to take away the skill you developed or perfected in making baking pans of course, which in your new job might involve creating new code or cannibalising the code you created whilst with your present employer. In legal terms, your current employer has paid you to write that code and it is theirs and not yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will it be seen as unprofessional or bad practise to take my code with me?

Typically yes. All the work you did for the company belongs to the company. The legality of taking it depends on your contract and local labor laws, but it would be unusual to allow it especially for a research company.

If you want to be nice, you can collect, organize it, document it and zip it all up into a single archive that's easy for them to store in a safe place as a backup.

> should I help them after I quit my job to continue fulfilling my tasks with no one in that position?

In order to do this, a few thing must be looked at

1. You actually want to do it. I don't see any ethical or moral obligation here for your to do anything.
2. You need to create a legal framework for your help. How do access confidential data, what is your liability, what is your compensation etc. Do NOT do that without a proper contract.
3. It must be ok with your future employer. Many employers have rules and policies about moonlighting: make sure you don't violate them

Comment: I'll do as you say @Hilmar, I don't think they can use it, but I'll collect and organize all my code and the reports into a zip file so they can have it if they need it.

Comment: #4 (or maybe #0) - work out how much you’d want to be paid to help them, and what basis (hourly rate? Per deliverable) and payment terms (weekly, monthly?) making sure it’s *at least* a fair market rate (but aim for higher if you like - you’re doing *them* a favour after all). If you do it for free or on the cheap they won’t have any incentive to find a replacement…

Answer (score 7):

> I understand that the reports and all their content, the databases and
> all the information they contain belong to the company. Will it be
> seen as unprofessional or bad practise to take my code with me?

Not only would it be unprofessional, but it could also cause you or anyone who receives it legal issues. In most cases, everything that you did for work belongs to the company. I would strongly recommend that you don't bring anything done for your employer, whether it's data or code or notes.

> I am almost certain that they won't ask for it because They don't have
> anyone capable of working with this data, but If they ask, should I
> help them after I quit my job to continue fulfilling my tasks with no
> one in that position?

There would be a lot of considerations here, and only you can decide what to do, but I'd lean toward "no".

One thing that you would need to consider is any agreements with your new employer. Some employment agreements prevent you from doing work for other companies, especially if it's related to your job function.

There are also reasons why you are leaving your current job. You even say that employees are treated badly. Why would you consider doing more work for an organization that is treating or is allowing their employees to be treated poorly? The organization should make sure that any work that you do is taken care of by people still in the organization, either on an ongoing basis or during your notice period, without any expectation of your availability once your leave.

Comment: In my academy setting, people know each other deeply, so I don't want to burn bridges. That's why, but I get your point. Thank you @Thomas Owens